# Dynamic componets renders the first time, but lose initialization when the father component reloads

Tags: reactjs, vite

I need help with this since I have tried literally everything but nothing seems to work and I don't understand this Reacts behavior

I am trying to create a MultiStep form, so I have all my steps in `index.js` inside the folder `data` like this

```
import PersonalInfo from '../components/PersonalInfo';
import SelectPlan from '../components/SelectPlan';
import AddOns from '../components/AddOns';
import FinishingUp from '../components/FinishingUp';

const steps = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Personal Info',
    component: PersonalInfo,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Select Plan',
    component: SelectPlan,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Add-ons',
    component: AddOns,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Summary',
    component: FinishingUp,
  },
];

...
```

To handle the steps and all the states I am using a customhook and a provider, the custom hook is this

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { MultistepProps } from '../@types/Multiform';

const useMultiStep = (steps: MultistepProps[]) => {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);

  const isLast = step === steps?.length - 1;
  const isFirst = step === 0;

  const next = (): void => {
    if (isLast) return;
    setStep((current) => current + 1);
  };

  const back = (): void => {
    if (isFirst) return;
    setStep((current) => current - 1);
  };

  return {
    step,
    next,
    back,
    currentStep: steps[step],
    isFirst,
  };
};

export default useMultiStep;
```

and the Provider looks like this

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import { MultiformContextType } from '../@types/Multiform';
import useMultiStep from '../hooks/useMultiStep';
import { FormData } from '../@types/Multiform';
import steps from '../data';

export type MultiformProviderProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
};

const MultiformContext = createContext<MultiformContextType | null>(null);

const MultiformProvider = ({ children }: MultiformProviderProps) => {
  const FORM_DATA: FormData = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    phone: '',
    planType: '0',
    offer: false,
  };

  const dataSteps = useMultiStep(steps);

  const { next, back, currentStep, isFirst } = dataSteps;

  const [data, setData] = useState<FormData>({ ...FORM_DATA });

  const handleData = (target: EventTarget & HTMLInputElement) => {
    setData((data: FormData) => {
      return {
        ...data,
        [target.name]: target.value,
      };
    });
  };

  const handleManualData = (name: string, value: boolean) => {
    setData((data: FormData) => {
      return { ...data, [name]: value };
    });
  };

  return (
    <MultiformContext.Provider
      value={{
        next,
        currentStep,
        handleData,
        back,
        data,
        isFirst,
        handleManualData,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </MultiformContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { MultiformProvider };

export default MultiformContext;
```

I am rendering the components in `App`

```
import FormInterface from './interface/FormInterface';
import useApp from './hooks/useApp';

function App() {
  const { currentStep, next, back, isFirst } = useApp();

  const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    next();
  };

  return (
    <FormInterface>
      <form
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        className="flex flex-col h-full py-5 group"
        noValidate={true}
      >
        {currentStep && (
          <>
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold text-marineBlue">
              {currentStep?.name}
            </h1>

            <currentStep.component />

            <div
              className={`mt-4 sm:mt-auto flex ${
                isFirst ? 'justify-end' : 'justify-between'
              }`}
            >
              <button
                type="button"
                className={`hover:text-marineBlue font-bold text-coolGray py-2 px-5 rounded-md text-[13px] ${
                  isFirst ? 'hidden' : 'block'
                }`}
                onClick={back}
              >
                Go Back
              </button>
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="hover:bg-purplishBlue bg-marineBlue text-white py-2 px-5 rounded-md text-[12px] group-invalid:pointer-events-none group-invalid:opacity-30 self-end"
              >
                Next Step
              </button>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </form>
    </FormInterface>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So the first time the component renders everything is great, I am using tailwindCSS so when I change a class this error appears

> react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367 ReferenceError: Cannot access 'PersonalInfo' before initialization
> at index.ts:13:16
> overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367
> warnFailedFetch @ client.ts:112
> fetchUpdate @ client.ts:448
> await in fetchUpdate (async)
> (anonymous) @ client.ts:159
> handleMessage @ client.ts:157
> (anonymous) @ client.ts:90
> Show 5 more frames
> react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367 [hmr] Failed to reload /src/components/PersonalInfo.tsx. This could be due to syntax errors or importing non-existent modules. (see errors above)
> overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend_compact.js:2367
> warnFailedFetch @ client.ts:114
> fetchUpdate @ client.ts:448
> await in fetchUpdate (async)
> (anonymous) @ client.ts:159
> handleMessage @ client.ts:157
> (anonymous) @ client.ts:90
> Show 5 more frames
> index.ts:13 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Cannot access 'PersonalInfo' before initialization
> at index.ts:13:16

Please help me out cause I am losing my mind, I have tried using Lazy and Suspense and it worked for some time, but when I added more logic to the components it stopped working, I simulated an asynchronous petition, tried conditional rendering, and nothing works! and I don't know why.